# CALayer animation for width

Tags: ios, swift, animation, calayer

I have one view in which need to add one layer. I successfully added the layer but now i want to do animation for it's width means layer start filling from "started" label and end at "awaiting..." label. I try to add animation with **CABasicAnimation** it start from beginning but it not properly fill. Please check video like for more understanding.

```
func startProgressAnimation()
    {
        self.ivStarted.isHighlighted = true
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4980392157, green: 0.8352941176, blue: 0.1921568627, alpha: 1)
        layer.masksToBounds = true

        layer.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.viewStartedAwaited.frame.origin.x, y: self.viewStartedAwaited.frame.origin.y, width: 0.0, height: self.viewStartedAwaited.frame.height)
        self.ivStarted.layer.addSublayer(layer)

        CATransaction.begin()

        let boundsAnim:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
        boundsAnim.fromValue = NSNumber.init(value: 0.0)
        boundsAnim.byValue = NSNumber.init(value: Float(self.viewStartedAwaited.frame.size.width / 2.0))
        boundsAnim.toValue = NSNumber.init(value: Float(self.viewStartedAwaited.frame.size.width))
        let anim = CAAnimationGroup()
        anim.animations = [boundsAnim]
        anim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        anim.duration = 5
        anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth

        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in
            self?.ivAwaited.isHighlighted = true
        }


        layer.add(anim, forKey: "bounds.size.width")
        CATransaction.commit()

    }
```

> Here is the video what i achieve with this code.
>   https://streamable.com/h6tpp

Not Proper

[image: Not Proper]

Proper image

[image: Proper image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your

```
layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

After this it will work according to your requirement.

The default anchorpoint of (0.5,0.5) means that the growing or shrinking of width happens evenly on both sides. Anchorpoint of (0,0) means the layer is essentially pinned to the top left, so whatever new width it gets, the change happens on the right. That is, it matters not whether your animation key path is 'bounds' or 'bounds.size.width'. The anchor point is what determines where the change happens

Comment: Let me try this